# Detecting click on multiple tables with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have developed code which detects when a user clicks on a cell in a table, and then uses the bgColor that has been set for that cell.

I have most of what I am trying to achieve working, I am stuck on how do get it to detect a click in multiple tables, instead of just one. I need to have this working with multiple tables, however I cannot have it working with all tables, just the colorchartX tables. So other tables on this page, should do nothing when their cell is clicked.

So in the code below, I have colorchart1 working as I want, how do I also get colorchart2 to detect when one of its cells is clicked and then provide the bgColor for that cell?

```
function getVal(e) {
    var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;

    var colorSelected = targ.attributes.bgcolor.value;
    alert(colorSelected);
}

onload = function() {
    var t = document.getElementById("colorchart1").getElementsByTagName("td");
    for ( var i = 0; i < t.length; i++ )
        t[i].onclick = getVal;
}


<table id="colorchart1">
<tr>
<td bgColor="#F8E0E0"></td><td bgColor="#F8ECE0"></td><td bgColor="#F7F8E0"></td><td   bgColor="#ECF8E0"></td>
<td bgColor="#E0F8E0"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8EC"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8F7"></td><td bgColor="#E0ECF8"></td><td bgColor="#E0E0F8"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td bgColor="#F5A9A9"></td><td bgColor="#F5D0A9"></td><td bgColor="#F2F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#D0F5A9"></td>
<td bgColor="#A9F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5D0"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5F2"></td><td bgColor="#A9D0F5"></td><td bgColor="#A9A9F5"></td>
</tr>
<table>

<table id="colorchart2">
<tr>
<td bgColor="#F8E0E0"></td><td bgColor="#F8ECE0"></td><td bgColor="#F7F8E0"></td><td   bgColor="#ECF8E0"></td>
<td bgColor="#E0F8E0"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8EC"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8F7"></td><td bgColor="#E0ECF8"></td><td bgColor="#E0E0F8"></td>
</tr><tr>
<td bgColor="#F5A9A9"></td><td bgColor="#F5D0A9"></td><td bgColor="#F2F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#D0F5A9"></td>
<td bgColor="#A9F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5D0"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5F2"></td><td bgColor="#A9D0F5"></td><td bgColor="#A9A9F5"></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ids = ['colorchart1', 'colorchart2'];
for(var j = 0; j < ids.length; j++) {
var t = document.getElementById(ids[j]).getElementsByTagName("td");
for ( var i = 0; i < t.length; i++ )
    t[i].onclick = getVal; 
}
```

Or - use jQuery and give all your tables a "colorchart" class then use the $('.colorchart') selector.